# batch/cmd find percentage of a number

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've had this problem for a while and havent found a solution, lets say i want to set the system volume to 50%, to do this i would do something like

```
set percent=50

set /a num=50/100
set /a num*=65535
nircmd setsysvolume %num%
```

but command prompt doesn't seem to support floating point numbers, only integers, so how would i do this without using floats?
keep in mind i want to be able to set the percentage to any number without changing the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

```
set percent=50

set /a "num=65535*(percent %% 101)/100"
nircmd setsysvolume %num%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set percent=50

set /a num=65535*percent/100
nircmd setsysvolume %num%
```